# How to determine the units when reading a multimeter?

Tags: multimeter

Say for instance I am trying to measure the current. The units around the edge of the multimeter is 2000u, 200m, 20m, 10A, etc.

Does this mean that the reading displayed on the multimeter is in that particular unit? For example, if I set it to 20m and the reading stated "0.5", does this mean it is 0.5 * 20mA = 10mA = 0.01A?

[image: Similar Multimeter]

Comment: Can you give us a link to an image of the multimeter?

Comment: [This](http://toolboxes.flexiblelearning.net.au/demosites/series12/12_04/toolbox1204/resources/01principles/07measurement/images/multimeter1.gif) is the closest thing I could find. I don't have access to the multimeter at the moment.

Note that the "terminals" on mine are "10A", "A", "COM", "V".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No the 'units' around the outside you are referring to are not units but ranges. If you set it to 20m, then the  highest current you can measure its 20mA. If you are on 20mA and it says 0.5, that probably means you are measuring 0.5mA.

There exist auto-ranging multimeters which you simply set to current mode and you don't have to worry about picking a range.

Comment: Damn, this means that much of my homework is wrong. :/

Comment: Ok, say for instance my multimeter was set to 2000µ (on the current) and the current reading was "0.10". Does this mean that the current was 0.10µ?

Comment: What are you doing 0.10µA is a pretty tiny amount of current. It is quite possibly saying 0.1mA, is the display showing 3 decimal places?

Comment: If set to 2000u it would need 6 digits to display 0.10

Comment: If the display units change, then there should be an indicator on the display to tell you the current unit, like a "uA" or "mA". So if the display says 0.5 and the "mA" designator is visible, then it's 0.5 mA, while if only an "A", or "Amp" indicator is visible, then it's 500mA.