# Why does my multimeter use increments of 2?

Tags: multimeter

I bought a cheap multimeter (etek 10709 if you are curious) from Walmart the other day to just check out a few readings on my cars ignition system.

While I have no problem getting the reading (in ohms) I noted that all the increments were in 2s, 200 2k 20k and so on.

Does this mean whatever readings I received must half to accommodate for this?

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/48581/how-to-determine-the-units-when-reading-a-multimeter?rq=1 whoops...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. I just means you can (for example) measure 0-199 on the 200 setting. That way the first digit is always 0 or 1; it's a small cost savings.

Comment: In such a case usually only the right two  segments of an '7'-segment display will be implemented, just enough to display a `1`. Indeed saves cost in display and its driver.